# Redirect sub.domain.cz/xxx to sub.domain.cz

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect anything after the slash to version without slash.

That means if somebody writes

> subdomain.domain.cz/420 (or any number)

it will redirect to

> subdomain.domain.cz/

I tried to create .htacess file with

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule subdomain.domain.cz/?(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.cz/$
```

However it doesnt work. I tried to modify it somehow but it always show some error like i have to many redirects.

Can I ask you for some help please? It's my first time working with .htaccess

Thank you!

Comment: How about `RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ / [R]`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
When I try some adress with /xxx it just shows 404 error.

Comment: can you test with `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`, just to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled (you should get 403 Forbidden)

Comment: also, make sure the file is called `.htaccess` :)

Comment: Haha, no worries.

However, i changed it, and now it shows 403 in title when I try to acces /something

--->>

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /123 on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Can you then revert to `RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ / [R]`, and test from shell, with `curl -v subdomain.domain.cz/420`

Comment: sorry, i am doing this first time, can i kindly ask you to explain it little bit?

i changed it in htaccess back to "RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ / [R]", but i dont understand what do you mean by "curl -v " 

Thank you

...... btw. when it is changed like this it works on domain.cz , but not on subdomain.domain.cz

Comment: Oh man, i found I am doing wrong. I thought .htaccess file is only in main folder but when i uploaded the file in subdomain folder it works now... So really sorry and thank you for your help. I am really dumb, hah.

Comment: np, glad we had it resolved :)